# What  kind of text formatting is valid on Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

What kind of and to what extent is formatting possible on Launchpad posts such as questions and bug reports?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Answered on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/150189):

> Launchpad does not support markup in
>   user entered content at this time. URL
>   and bug numbers are linked by the
>   formatter that preserves blank lines.

Please support [this bug for a Launchpad wiki](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/240067).

Comment: The bug # and lp: markups disprove this theory...

Comment: @dan3 Those aren't markups: although they cause linkification, they appear as written in the text that is displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link points to a different problem than the quoted text (wiki support vs formatting/markup support). The two subjects are related but not equal. I would prefer having a more explicit bug (feature request) for supporting...

Answer (score 16):

I've found it quite difficult/impossible to find any infos about that on help.launchpad.net. The little I know I found by trial-and-error. Most important for me (and the only special formatting I use often) is, that writing "bug #xxxxx" (without quotes) in a bug comment automatically creates a link to the respective bug report.

Comment: Glad as I am not to the black sheep of the family (was worried I did not look hard enough), the lack of formatting feature is quite unfortunate. Ask Ubuntu's easy formatting tags on Launchpad would be wonderful.

Comment: lp:projectname also auto links, that's about it.

Comment: Even documenting bug # and lp: would be a start. I know about bug # and I still can't remember it when I need it.

Answer (score 4):

So the idea that Launchpad does not support formatting is only a myth... sort of. For the truly determined,

http://www.panix.com/~eli/unicode/convert.cgi?text=Is+Jorge+Castro+a+Robot?

```
   Parenthesized    ⒤⒮ ⒥⒪⒭⒢⒠ ⒞⒜⒮⒯⒭⒪ ⒜ ⒭⒪⒝⒪⒯?
   Circled  Ⓘⓢ Ⓙⓞⓡⓖⓔ Ⓒⓐⓢⓣⓡⓞ ⓐ Ⓡⓞⓑⓞⓣ?
   Negative Circled     ?
   Squared      ?
   Negative Squared     ?
   Fullwidth    Ｉｓ Ｊｏｒｇｅ Ｃａｓｔｒｏ ａ Ｒｏｂｏｔ？
   Double-struck      ℂ  ℝ?
   Bold     ?
   Bold italic      ?
   Bold script      ?
   Fraktur      ?
   Curvy 1 pseudoalphabet   ٱร ﻝѻɼﻭﻉ ƈครՇɼѻ ค ɼѻ๒ѻՇ?
   Curvy 2 pseudoalphabet   ιѕ נσяﻭє ¢αѕтяσ α яσвσт?
   Curvy 3 pseudoalphabet   เร ן๏гﻮє ςครՇг๏ ค г๏๒๏Շ?
   Rock Dots pseudoalphabet Їṡ Jöṛġë Ċäṡẗṛö ä Ṛöḅöẗ?
   A-cute pseudoalphabet    íś Jőŕǵé Ćáśtŕő á Ŕőbőt?
   Small Caps pseudoalphabet    ɪꜱ ᴊᴏʀɢᴇ ᴄᴀꜱᴛʀᴏ ᴀ ʀᴏʙᴏᴛ?
   Stroked pseudoalphabet   Ɨs Ɉøɍǥɇ ȻȺsŧɍø Ⱥ Ɍøƀøŧ?
   CJK+Thai pseudoalphabet  ﾉ丂 ﾌo尺g乇 cﾑ丂ｲ尺o ﾑ 尺o乃oｲ?
   Faux Cyrillic pseudoalphabet Іѕ ЈоѓБэ Ҁаѕтѓо а Яоъот?
   Upside down pseudoalphabet   ıs ɾoɹƃǝ ɔɐsʇɹo ɐ ɹoqoʇ¿
   Upside down pseudoalphabet (backwards)   ¿ʇoqoɹ ɐ oɹʇsɐɔ ǝƃɹoɾ sı
   Reversed pseudoalphabet  Iꙅ Joᴙgɘ ↃAꙅTᴙo A ᴙodoT⸮
   Reversed pseudoalphabet (backwards)  ⸮Todoᴙ A oᴙTꙅAↃ ɘgᴙoJ ꙅI
```

http://adamvarga.com/strike/

P̶o̶p̶e̶y̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶a̶m̶e̶.̶

http://thejh.net/misc/unicode-underline

P̲o̲p̲e̲y̲ ̲i̲s̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲e̲e̲s̲ ̲k̲n̲e̲e̲s̲

And you can actually combine these

http://www.panix.com/~eli/unicode/convert.cgi?text=M%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6i%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6c%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6h%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6a%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6l%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6H%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6a%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6l%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6l%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6a%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6t%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6s%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6u%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6b%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6b%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6f%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6o%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6s%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6u%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6p%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6p%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6a%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6n%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6d%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6h%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6a%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6s%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6c%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6h%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6i%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6c%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6k%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6n%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6f%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6o%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6+%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6t%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6i%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6r%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6e%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6s%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6.%CC%B6%CC%B2%CC%B6

Comment: That's not really formatting or markup support. It's just **unicode** support. However, as Launchpad haven't yet implemented markup support, tricks like this are the only way to do some formatting. Infact, this can be used on pretty much any site having unicode support, for eg; **Google+**. So, thanks anyway @akiva . This'll come handy!

Comment: Thank you, I used the `Math monospace` option to format Terminal commands and their output :)